# How can I extract the DataCompy comparison results?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am comparing two DataFrames using DataCompy.

How can I extract the results or create a log of results?

Is it possible to edit the results as well? Like remove certain line or modify the results. I know it's a automated process.

Here's the code:

```
for index, row in df_sqlfile.iterrows():
    sql = row["Query"]
    con = create_con(uname_d1, pword_d1, hname_d1, port_d1, sname_d1)
    header_db1 , row_db1 = read_query(con,sql)
    df_db1 = pd.DataFrame(list(row_db1), columns = header_db1)

    con1 = create_con(uname_d2, pword_d2, hname_d2, port_d2, sname_d2)
    header_db2, row_db2 = read_query(con1,sql)
    df_db2 = pd.DataFrame(list(row_db2), columns = header_db2)
    print(df_db2)

    comp = datacompy.Compare(
        df_db1,
        df_db2,
        join_columns = header_db1,
        abs_tol=0,
        rel_tol=0,
        df1_name='Original',
        df2_name='New'
        )

    comp.matches(ignore_extra_columns=False)
    print(comp.report())
```

Comment: Can anyone help me on how to create a log.txt of Datacompy comparision results

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to assign to a variable and convert into string and format it. If you want to get specific validations you can use them as below:

1. comp.all_mismatch() - gives mismatches between source and target
2. comp.df_db1_unq_rows - Gives values only present in source(df_db1 is nothing but your source dataframe)
3. comp.df_db2_unq_rows - Gives values only present in target(df_db2 is nothing but your target dataframe)